# Prove Poissons' theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

Let $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space. If $A_1, A_2, \ldots$ are independent events and $\bar{p}_n$ and $N$ are defined as
$$ \bar{p}_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{P}(A_i) \quad \text{and} \quad N_n=\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{1}_{A_i}$$
then $\frac{N_n}{n}-\bar{p}_n \to 0$ in probability.

This problem is from Billingsley (3rd edition, #6.5). I currently have the laws of large numbers at my disposal but since the sequence here is not i.i.d., I guess I need to invoke heavier machinery. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a corollary of Chebyshev's inequality. Fix $\delta > 0$. Then since $\mathbb E(N_n/n) = \overline p_n$, 
$$
\mathbb P \left( \left| \frac{N_n}n - \overline p_n \right| \ge \delta \right) \le \frac{\mathrm{Var}(N_n/n)}{\delta^2}.
$$
It suffices to show now that the variance of $N_n/n$ goes to $0$. It is not hard to show that $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ defined by $x \mapsto x(1-x)$ has a maximum at $x = 1/2$ which implies $f(x) \le 1/4$. Now
$$
\mathrm{Var}(N_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathrm{Var}(\mathbb 1_{A_i}) = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb P(A_i)(1-\mathbb P(A_i)) \le \frac n4,
$$
hence $\mathrm{Var}(N_n/n) \le \frac 1{4n} \to 0$.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** compute 
$$\mathbb E\left(\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n\{\chi_{A_i}-\mu(A_i)\}\right)^2.$$